# Converting varchar to nvarchar in SQL Server failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, type-conversion

I have SQL Server table that contains columns of type `varchar(50)` as a result of a CSV import using the SQL Server Import wizard.

I was wanting to know how I can change this data type to `nvarchar(9)` without getting a SQL Server truncation error.

I tried doing a bulk update to set the data types and column sizes that I need but still had the truncation error message when I tried to load the csv into the empty database table I created (with my required data types that I need).

Grateful for any help.

Comment: How do you plan to store, for instance, text `"how I can change this data type to nvarchar (9) without getting a SQL Server truncation error"` in column of type `nvarchar(9)` ?

Comment: Are you willing to lose data if there is more than 9 characters in that column ?

Comment: Hi, I will be storing the converted data in the same SQl SERVER table but in new nvarchar (9) size fields within same table

Comment: Hi M Ali yes I am willing to lose data. As it stands the VARCHAR 50 columns are too big for the data it contains. The data within the column is length 9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are willing to lose data and nvarchar will only be able to store 9 non-unicode charaters, then select only 9 characters from your source table, You do the truncation rather than Sql server doing it for you.

The Following Query will trim any White spaces from the strings, Then take only 9 characters from the string and convert them to NVARCHAR(9) for you.....

```
CREATE TABLE New_TABLE (Col1 NVARCHAR(9), Col2 NVARCHAR(9))
GO

INSERT INTO New_TABLE (Col1, Col2)
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9),LEFT(LTRIM(Col1), 9))  
      ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(9),LEFT(LTRIM(Col2), 9))
FROM Existing_Table
GO
```

Comment: Hi M Ali I get an Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of ltrim function. But I used an Update statement to set the nvarchar (9) columns to (LEFT(LTRIM(Col1), 9). I updated the nvarchar (9) columns perfectly. Sincere Thanks Dave

Answer (score 1):

Bulk insert into temp table with varchar(50) and insert to actual table

```
insert into tableName 
select cast(tempcolumn as nvarchar(9)) from temptable
```

Answer (score 0):

And it is also important to check field types of destination table. Just spent 3 hours because of same error with random casting, trimming, substring and at the end noticed, that colleague created table with too short field lengths.
I hope it helps somebody...

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error during Import/Export Tasks, you can use the `select cast(xxx as nvarchar(yyy)) as someName` in the "Write a query to specify the data to transfer" option

Answer (score 0):

varchar and nvarchar only use the length needed for the data stored. If you need unicode support certainly convert to nvarchar, but modifying it from 50 to 9 - what is the point?

If your data is ALWAYS exactly 9, consider using char(9), and following one of the transformation suggestions above...